# Is there A Mechanism In Place that Prevent Address 'Squatting'?

Tags: bitcoind, address

Is there a function or mechanism in the bitcoin protocol that prevents someone from creating millions or billions of bitcoin addresses and just sitting on them? Do the addresses need a minimum balance of outputs? or Does that distributed DB save each address? (And if it is saved....what is saved?  The base58 address or the full Public Key? I am also familiar with the ecdsa algorithm.)

Comment: Hi raoa, it is customary here to ask only about one topic per question, as our system works best with narrow topics that may be linked to similar questions. I've tried to provide a short answer below and added some links for further reading. As I think all your questions have answers on Bitcoin.SE already, I have closed your question as a duplicate of a question that appears to answer your main query. If you are interested in finding out more about our site, please check out our short and vivid **[tour]**.

Answer (score 2):

The network doesn't require proven ownership to make an address valid, otherwise one would never be able to send bitcoins to a new address. Any address in the address space can receive a transaction at any time. Also see here: 
[At what point is a new wallet known by the Bitcoin network?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13225/5406)

Creating a great number of addresses is possible, but impractical, because the address space is simply too big for anyone to even store a significant portion of the addresses. See a more thorough explanation here:
[Is it possible to brute force bitcoin address creation in order to steal money?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/22/5406)

Assuming the "That distributed DB" refers to the Blockchain, the Blockchain stores every transaction ever made on the Bitcoin network. See [What is the “blockchain”?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/168/5406) and [Where are the user's bitcoins actually stored?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1600/5406).